# CSS text-shadow in Mobile Browsers

Tags: html, css, web, shadow, stroke

I'm trying to use the following style to create a text-stroke using text-shadow:

```
.text-stroke {
text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 white,
1px -1px 0 white,
-1px 1px 0 white,
1px 1px 0 white;
}
```

It doesn't work for the mobile versions of Firefox and Chrome. Is there anything I can do to make it work in mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You can view in in [Can i use](http://caniuse.com/#search=text%20shadow) website. It's show you the browser supports of CSS tags.

Chrome for Android 39 or heighter version.

Edit:

Set the blur radius to 1px or heighter.

Comment: So you provided a link to a site that doesn't mention FireFox mobile and claims that Chrome for Android should support it. How does this answer the question?

Comment: Fair enough, but still no indication as why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is **Polyfills**.

I.e, use CSS `text-shadow` where supported, and use a css `background-image`, where unsupported.

See http://modernizr.com/ for detection of support of text-shadow among others.

Tutorial on how to use Modernizr: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/modernizr/

TLDR:

Modernizr will add a CSS class `.no-textshadow` to your `HTML` element, if it detects that the browser does not support text-shadows.

Then it's a matter of providing a fallback in your CSS along the lines of `.no-textshadow .text-stroke{}`